# MySQL - ORDER BY not taken into account

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this code ; It is supposed to display all tables from my primary database, and their records.

It works, but the "ORDER BY" isn't taken into account, the records displays something like

- table1:45
- table2:7
- table3:128

And I want an output like this :

- table3:128
- table1:45
- table2:7

Can someone tell me what is wrong in my code ? Thank you so much !

```
SELECT (SELECT (@container) 
          FROM (SELECT (@container:=0x00),
                 (SELECT (@container)
                   FROM (information_schema.columns)
                   WHERE (table_schema = database)
                   AND (@container:=CONCAT(@container,table_name,0x3a,table_rows,0x3c6272202f3e))
                   ORDER BY table_rows DESC
                 )
               )
         a);
```

EDIT : I created a false table here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ed0b2
But still, no clue ; The query sorts the output by table_rows ASC even though I asked it DESC

Comment: You can try order by in last outer query as @LoztlnSpace suggested...if you need more support then create a #sqlfiddle so that it can be checked practically...

Comment: how do I do that ? :)

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: go to above link provided by Bhawin and create schema and insert statements in left pane and your query in right pane.

Comment: @ZafarMalik Note that the query is against metadata.

Comment: @Taemyr: I think after creating even a dummy table in left pane, we can query in system db also like information_schema etc...

Comment: @ZafarMalik Or you could use just press build schema directly and run the query against an empty schema.  It will not matter, sqlfiddle fails with an error message. - For both MySql 5.5 and 5.6.

Comment: @Sharkky Please provide the link to the fiddle with the querry you are running.

Answer (score 1):

Inner order by statements are only relevant to limit clauses and stuff like that. The order by on the final, outermost  select is what will order the output.  I wish inner order by was a syntax error.

I'm not overly familiar with the guts of MySQL so that may not be the actual problem in this case.

Edit:
The asc/desc is a side effect of the inner sort being removed/ignored. You need to sort on the outermost select